# No user when pushing notebooks from Databricks to Azure DevOps Repos when using DB Repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

I have my code in a Azure DevOps repos., and use Azure Databricks to execute and develop my code.

I am using the Repos functionality in Databricks where I can connect to my code repos, commit and push code to my branch in DevOps.

When creating a new branch from Databricks it is created with no problem, and I can see in DevOps that the branch is created with me as owner.

I am though having a problem when committing/pushing my changes from the Databricks interface. My pushes show up in DevOps without any user, and just shows a empty user.

Has anybody experienced this, and have a fix for it ?

Comment: Could you please share us some details steps to help us know your issue? On my side, I follow this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/azure-devops-services-version-control#notebook-integration) guidance, and try to commit/push to my test project. It works well.

Comment: it's better to provide feedback to the Repos team on Databricks - because this is preview feature, some stuff may not work properly in some situations

Comment: I have provided feedback, and they are aware of this problem, and fixing it in a future realese... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This was a know issue by Databricks. I've reach out to them and they have a fix on the way.